# Convert recursive algorithm to iterative algorithm

Tags: c#, recursion

Hi i have a problem about recursive algorithm.
This code run too long. I already search from Internet and I have a plan to change the algorithm from recursive to iterative.

I have difficulty to change the code since there is no "return" condition (It always loop until list of years, types, operations, locations, departments, and positions are finished).

How to change the algorithm??

Here are the code:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
var years = GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment(new string[] { string.Empty }, group);
foreach (var year in years)
{
   var types = GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment(new string[] { year.Year.ToString() }, group);
   foreach (var type in types)
   {
      var departments = GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment(new string[] { year.Year.ToString(), type.ContractorType }, group);
      foreach (var department in departments)
      {
          var operations = GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment(new string[] { year.Year.ToString(), type.ContractorType, department.Department }, group);
          foreach (var operation in operations)
          {
             var positions = GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment(new string[] { year.Year.ToString(), type.ContractorType, department.Department, operation.Operation }, group);
             foreach (var position in positions)
             {
                 var locations = GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment(new string[] { year.Year.ToString(), type.ContractorType, department.Department, operation.Operation, position.Position }, group);
                 foreach (var location in locations)
                 {
                    DataTable tbl = ReportExport.ConvertToDataTable<ReportMonthlyFTE>(
                                   GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment(new string[] { year.Year.ToString(), type.ContractorType, department.Department, operation.Operation, position.Position, location.Location }, group).ToList());
                                    dataSet.Tables.Add(tbl);
                 }
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you are confusing iterative and recursive. the code you posted is fully iterative. it uses for-loops instead of call to itself

Comment: what does GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment() do?  It's getting called a lot and is likely the cause of your performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the function GetDataForReportMonthlyFTEWorkCompletionByDepartment() call query from sql server (select)  based on parameter given

Comment: Yes, looks like I'm confusing between iterative and recursive, Sorry

Comment: Do you really want to call this for *every* year, type, department, operation, position, and location combination?? If so, you should probably just have a query pull the whole table back and then loop over it with *one* for loop with C#.

Answer (score 0):

I think `yield` might solve your problem.  This will allow you to control enumeration from the calling code so you may escape early when you need to.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var dataTable in GetData())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got more data.");

            Console.WriteLine("Continue getting more data?");
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

            if (keyInfo.KeyChar != 'y')
            { 
                // Stop enumerating.
                break; 
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static IEnumerable<DataTable> GetData()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new DataTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Also notice the return type `IEnumerable<out T>`.